# Passing values to multiple dynamically created controls base on bootstrap-3-typeahead dropdown list using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

I am creating an invoice system using Laravel, JQuery and Bootstrap-3-typeahead and have created a button that dynamically adds new table row with text inputs in each table data on selection of a list item using JQuery. The first text input in each row has bootstrap-3-typeahead functionality: After selecting an item like this
[creating invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79khU.png) tutorial.

After selecting from the autocomplete text-input dropdown list, it automatically populates the price, quantity and assign a default value of "1" to the quantity input using the below Typeahead(afterSelect method) implementation using JQuery and Ajax GET method.

**This is my**
[html markup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAq4e.png).

**My JQuery implementation of boostrap-3-typeahead and generation of auto price, quantity, and total values base on selected item from typeahead dropdown list.**

```js
var typeaheadSettings = {
  source: function (query, process) {
    return $.get(url, { query: query }, function (data) {
      console.log(data)
      return process(data);
    });
  },
  afterSelect: function (data) {
    console.log(data.sellPrice);          

    $('#itemPrice').val(data.sellPrice);
    $('#itemQuantity').val('1');
    var price = $('#itemPrice').val();
    var quantity = $('#itemQuantity').val();
    var subtotal = price * quantity;
    $('#itemSubtotal').val(subtotal);
  }
};
```

**The JS code that adds new row on button click:**

```js
// Add Row
$(document).on('click', '#btnAddRow', function(event) {
  var i=$('#invoiceTable tbody tr').size();
  html = '<tr>';
  html += '<td><p class="text-center pt-xs"><input type="radio" name="sn" id="sn" value=""></p></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="productName[]" id="itemName'+ i +'" class="form-control typeahead twitter-typeahead" placeholder="Item name" autocomplete="off" data-fit-to-element="true" data-provide="typeahead"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="itemPrice'+i+'" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="Item price" autocomplete="off" readonly></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="itemQuantity'+ i +'" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="Quantity"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="subtotal[]" id="itemSubtotal'+ i +'" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="Subtotal" readonly></td>';
  html += '<td class="actions-hover actions-fade text-center"><p><a id="btnDelRow"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg text-warning" id="iconDelRow"></i></a></p></td>';
  html += '</tr>';

  $('#invoiceTable tbody').append(html);
  i++;
  $('.typeahead').trigger('added');
});
```

This is what the markup of the dynamically added row looks like, with integer "1,2" suffixed to the ID.The integer increments if another row is added dynamically, giving all duplicate controls a unique ID.
[dynamically added tr screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtSvx.png)

The problem is that when i add a second control dynamically by clicking the "Add New Row" button shown on the image above, the dynamically added price and quantity input controls don't get the newly generated values. Instead, the values appear on the first already defined row. The same thing happens when i add the 3rd row and more.
I'd be glad if someone can help me out with a way i can pass the values generated after dropdown list item is selected to the right or appropriate inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML selector you are using seems to be an ID selector which should be unique per document. This may explain why this is happening.

Comment: I've edited the question now. The exact thing i want todo can be found her http://www.smarttutorials.net/jquery-autocomplete-multiple-fields-using-ajax-php-mysql-example/     Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the values appear on the first defined row because you have coded only their IDs into the typeaheadSettings.afterSelect(...) function:

```
    $('#itemPrice').val(data.sellPrice);
    $('#itemQuantity').val('1');
    var price = $('#itemPrice').val();
    var quantity = $('#itemQuantity').val();
    var subtotal = price * quantity;
    $('#itemSubtotal').val(subtotal);
```

You should probably refactor the function so it can use the other auto-generated IDs like `#itemPrice1`, `#itemSubtotal2`, ...